# Magento 2 - Invalid Form Key for new storeview

Tags: forms, store-view, form-validation, stores, form-key

I created a new storeview and noticed that I can't log in as a customer. It works on the main store view perfectly fine. There are no errors in the server and magento logfiles.

I always get: "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page. "

I disabled ALL third party modules and changed my theme to magento luma, but I still get the error.

Magento Version: 2.3.4-p2

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the cookie domain of my new store view.

It was set to the same as the website "company.com" I changed it to "app.company.com"

Credits to [blog.expertrec.com](https://blog.expertrec.com/magento-2-3-invalid-form-key/)